# Is it possible to initialise ORM module with dynamic parameters in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nrwl-nx, mikro-orm

I'm using `NX` monorepo with `NestJs` apps (`auth-service`, `other-service`, etc.).

I also created separated library for storing migrations `libs/database.migrations` and another library `libs/database.mikro-orm` for `MikroORM` initialisation (to be reusable).

Library `database.mikro-orm` should be imported into other apps or libraries to connect to DB. Main obstacle is, when I import `DatabaseMikroOrmModule` into auth service `AppModule`, I want to pass all entities to `DatabaseMikroOrmModule` and dynamically add to `MikroOrmModule > entities`.

Here's how my `DatabaseMikroOrmModule` looks like:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MikroOrmModule } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MikroOrmModule.forRoot({
      entities: [ /* ENTITIES PASSED FROM OTHER APPS OR LIBS SHOULD GO HERE */],
      dbName: 'experimental-db',
      type: 'postgresql',
    }),
  ],
  ...
})
export class DatabaseMikroOrmModule {
  public static setEntities(entities) {
    /* MAY BE SOMEHOW ADD THEM FROM HERE */
  }
}
```

From the app:

```
import { DatabaseMikroOrmModule } from '@database.mikro-orm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseMikroOrmModule.setEntities([UserEntity, RoleEntity])],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using nestjs dynamic modules check [dynamic modules wanago](https://wanago.io/2022/08/15/api-with-nestjs-dynamic-modules/)
or [nest js docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules)